# Extraction of characters and symbols using R

Tags: r, substring

I have a column with these kind of values

```
                    id     count  total SEXO EDAD IDENTIF_AFILIADO
 1:  952815090_12_06_Q643     4 133.34    M   39        952815090
 2:   952443257_10_17_C64     9  64.32    F    5        952443257
 3:   931131767_9_10_C716     2  21.88    M    1        931131767
 4:   931131767_8_13_C716    15 173.70    M    1        931131767
 5:   931131767_1_09_C716     1  10.94    M    0        931131767
```

.....

The **id** column has a code after the third " _ ". For instance, the first row has **"952815090_12_06_Q643"**

I need to extrac the  code **Q643**.

More specifically the group of characters after the third "_" in every row. How to perform it using R?

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```r
gsub("^.*_.*_.*_(.*)$", "\\1", id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```r
your.ids <- sapply( dat$id, function(id) {
    strsplit( id, "_" )[[1]][4]
})
```

Or if this is a data.table, perhaps something like this:

```r
dat[, idstring := tstrsplit( id, "_", fixed=T )[4] ]
```

Applied to your code it looks like this:

```r
dat <- read.table(text=
"                    id     count  total SEXO EDAD IDENTIF_AFILIADO
 1:  952815090_12_06_Q643     4 133.34    M   39        952815090
 2:   952443257_10_17_C64     9  64.32    F    5        952443257
 3:   931131767_9_10_C716     2  21.88    M    1        931131767
 4:   931131767_8_13_C716    15 173.70    M    1        931131767
 5:   931131767_1_09_C716     1  10.94    M    0        931131767
") %>% as.data.table

dat[, idstring := tstrsplit( id, "_", fixed=T )[4] ]

print( dat )
```

Output:

```
                     id count  total SEXO EDAD IDENTIF_AFILIADO idstring
1: 952815090_12_06_Q643     4 133.34    M   39        952815090     Q643
2:  952443257_10_17_C64     9  64.32    F    5        952443257      C64
3:  931131767_9_10_C716     2  21.88    M    1        931131767     C716
4:  931131767_8_13_C716    15 173.70    M    1        931131767     C716
5:  931131767_1_09_C716     1  10.94    M    0        931131767     C716
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but When I run this code, I got Q643 en every row¡. I need to get  C64 for the first row, C64 in the second row..... etcc

Comment: I had a bug in my first version of the answer, make sure you are using the current code. (the one using `tstrsplit`)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete everything until last underscore.

```
sub('.*_', '', df$id)
#[1] "Q643" "C64"  "C716" "C716" "C716"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("952815090_12_06_Q643", "952443257_10_17_C64", 
"931131767_9_10_C716", "931131767_8_13_C716", "931131767_1_09_C716"
), count = c(4L, 9L, 2L, 15L, 1L), total = c(133.34, 64.32, 21.88, 
173.7, 10.94), SEXO = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), EDAD = c(39L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 0L), IDENTIF_AFILIADO = c(952815090L, 952443257L, 
931131767L, 931131767L, 931131767L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```